# Generate an array with the Months in F#

Tags: f#

How can I generate a array with all the Months of the year in F#?

I've tried:

```
let array = [|"January", "February", ... |]
```

Is there a simply way to make it?

Comment: You could probably loop by adding months to a `System.DateTime`, but really typing 12 words isn't that hard and the loop wouldn't be that much shorter.

Comment: don't think there's an easier way..

Comment: You want an array of strings or an array of (int*string) -- that is an array with month number and month name?  There's a difference and you may want to edit your question to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx)?

> Gets or sets a one-dimensional array of type String containing the culture-specific full names of the months.

Note it's culture-specific, though...

Comment: like this?    let arrayMonth = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames

Comment: Yes. You could specify a culture of course, if you want: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat.MonthNames`

Comment: @ThomasFey You'll probably also want to remove the 13th element, which is an empty string. Another way is: `[1 .. 12] |> List.map culture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName`